# htaccess redirect to no slash with rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this rewrite rule in my htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^my-old-parent/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

It will redirect:

```
example.com/my-old-parent/child/
```

To:

```
example.com/child/
```

But I want it to redirect to:

```
example.com/child
```

I've seen a few solutions but they are all doing it in two steps which means two redirects. I want just one redirect.

Any ideas? Maybe some search replace `/` with nothing or some regex solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below rule,

```
RewriteRule ^my-old-parent/(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```